# CSS background: url, no work when the url have brackets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I have the next url for an image

url: http://www.andrearosseti.cl/image/cache/data/New%20Coleccion/Planas/SWEET-5-TAUPE-(1)-340x340.jpg

Now, i wont make in my CSS

```
background: url(http://www.andrearosseti.cl/image/cache/data/New%20Coleccion/Planas/SWEET-5-TAUPE-(1)-340x340.jpg)
```

the problem is the brackets in the url.

[image]

i try scape the bracket, but not work.

Any ideas?

I use Rails and SCSS

Thank

Comment: Take the brackets out of the file name... Sorted.

Comment: i can't modify that url. The Client send me that url

Comment: I don't even get an image when pointing my browser to the given URL.

Comment: Yeah - the URL you posted goes to a `404` not found page!

Comment: http://www.andrearosseti.cl/image/cache/data/New%20Coleccion/Planas/SWEET-5-TAUPE-%281%29-600x600.jpg - that works, it was the bit between `new` and `Coleccion` that was broken.

Comment: Sorry, now yes, the correct url is http://www.andrearosseti.cl/image/cache/data/New%20Coleccion/Planas/SWEET-5-TAUPE-(1)-340x340.jpg

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go: Put `\` in-front of the brackets.

### HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

### CSS:

```
div {
    background: url(http://www.andrearosseti.cl/image/cache/data/New%20Coleccion/Planas/SWEET-5-TAUPE-\(1\)-340x340.jpg);
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/L5Ju9/)

Comment: @rudighert Isn't this braces escaping that you said you already tried in the question? How did you try to escape the braces then?

Answer (score 2):

Replace braces with encoded braces chars:

```
div {
    background: url(http://www.andrearosseti.cl/image/cache/data/New%20Coleccion/Planas/SWEET-5-TAUPE-%281%29-340x340.jpg);
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the url with quotes:

```
background: url('http://www.andrearosseti.cl/image/cache/data/New%20Coleccion/Planas/SWEET-5-TAUPE-(1)-600x600.jpg')
```

Comment: @rudighert Is the url encoded with `%25`? In that case, add quotes and change `%25` with `%`.

Comment: Single or double quote the `URL`. Also the current URL goes to a 404 page, `New%252520Coleccion` should be `New%20Coleccion`

Comment: sorry, the correct URL is http://www.andrearosseti.cl/image/cache/data/New%20Coleccion/Planas/SWEET-5-TAUPE-(1)-340x340.jpg